# [Android]How to set final for AlertDialog in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want using AlertDialog to show calendar when I touch on Edit Text in fragment. In the past, when i using Activity class, it worked perfect. But when I using Fragment,  It is not working.

Here is method to show calendar dialog when touch edit text in Fragment:

```
 private void setDateTimeField() {
    try {
        et_date.setOnClickListener(this);

        final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth - 1);
                if (newDate.getTime().getTime() > (newCalendar.getTime().getTime())) {

                    final  AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Notification").setMessage("This is a date of future! We will get current date for this review!").show();

                    //this code below is coppied in https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/auto-close-dialog-after-a-specific-time/
                    final Timer t = new Timer();
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        public void run() {
                            builder.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
                            t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
                        }
                    }, 2000); // after 2 second (or 2000 miliseconds), the task will be active.
                    et_date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newCalendar.getTime()));

                } else {
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    et_date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                }
            }
        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        messages("Something Wrong!");
    }
}
```

It's wrong at:

```
 final  AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Notification").setMessage("This is a date of future! We will get current date for this review!").show();
```

[image: You can see this error here]
When i remove final for builder, this code above is ok, but other problem appear at:

```
builder.dismiss();
```

[image: You can see this error here]
This code above requires builder must be final. I know the best solution for my question is using DialogFragment. But I don't want using it. Moreover, I want know the reason for this error.  Please help me. 
p/s: My english is not good so I'm so sorry if i have any wrong in grammar and thanks you for reading my question.

Comment: This may sound weird, but haven't you forget to create() AlertDialog?

Comment: @Reiz It's create on this code. So sorry but it's not my problem. If i using this code on Avtivity class, nothing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
```

to

```
fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
```

Comment: Thanks you bro, I will try it now.

Comment: It show the same error :(. can not add final in dismiss.

Comment: It is not a hidden error, when I add final on builder or dissmiss, android studio show all code in method onDateSet are wrong.  If I remove final, the android studio show error in dissmis (if i put final at AlertDialog) and vice versa.

Comment: I will take a picture for you, please wait a few minutes.

Comment: I should have realized it ealier, because you mentioned that it was working in `Activity`, but it is not working in `Fragment`. Also now you see how important is to add detailed error :)

Comment: Thanks bro, It's not show error on android studio, but i have an other error when debug, so i will fix it and check your solution. I think it's right. Thanks you again.